# Staking Marathon Website Scam

Tags: accounts, security, ledger-nano

I was on that **Staking Marathon Scam** website too. I had arround 90 XLM on my Ledger account. They said it is not enough. (I wanted to test it.) Days later I sent all my XLM (20k+) to my Ledger account. Now I have checked everything and know it is a scam.

When I connect now the Ledger, is it possible that hey have access to my account cause I was one time connected to them? Maybe they know through this my PK?
Or does it also need the manual connection I surely never will give?

Comment: By ledger do you mean the hardware?

Comment: Yes. I connect with Ledger live, but of course not with the scam side. So this should be not a problem or? My fear is, that they have something like my private-keys cause we was one time connected, when they rejected cause it was not enough XLM for them..

Answer (score 0):

The ledger hardware is designed so that the secret never leaves the key. The only way you can get into trouble with an account that has the secret stored on ledger is

- losing the ledger **and** recovery phrase
- you signing malicious transactions with your ledger